why is FSDP not sharding my model between GPUs?
I have a model that is too large even if the batch size is 1 to fit on a single GPU. So I looked into it and it seems that FSDP is the proper way to handle this. Below, I have some code where I manually wrap a few of my layers, and check the amount of GPU memory being used before and after some of the modules where a large portion of memory is being used. From here I saw that only one of the 2 GPUs available were being used, while the other GPU had only 3 bytes of memory allocated on it. This is my model:
class LightningModel_distributed_patch_16(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LightningModel_distributed_patch_16, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        total_depths = 10
        self.original_model =  patchedSeg_l(attentions=[attentions.SelfAttention_big, attentions.SelfAttention_big], depths=[total_depths, total_depths], positioned=[True, True], dim_3=False, attentions1_depth=(4,4), img_h=256, img_w=256, heads=12, patches=(16,16))
        self.original_model.pos_embed = Summer(PositionalEncodingPermute3D(3))
        self.pos_embed = self.original_model.pos_embed
        self.transformers1 = self.original_model.transformers1
        self.to_patches = self.original_model.to_patches
        self.conv1 = self.original_model.conv1
        self.conv2 = self.original_model.conv2
        self.bn1 = self.original_model.bn1
        self.bn2 = self.original_model.bn2
        self.bn3 = self.original_model.bn2
        self.relu = self.original_model.relu
        self.transformer_0 = self.original_model.transformer_0

        #all the modules before this on cuda:0
        #all the modules after this on cuda:1
        self.transformer_1 = self.original_model.transformer_1
        self.transformers_out = self.original_model.transformers_out
        self.conv_out = self.original_model.conv_out
        self.out_layer = self.original_model.out_layer
        self.from_patches = attentions.FromPatches(16,16, False)

        self.batch_size = 256
        self.store_losses_printing = []
        self.store_correct_number = []
        self.store_correct_percent = []
        self.store_losses_printing_val = []

        self.s_logits = []

                

    def configure_sharded_model(self):
        self.trainer.model.transformers1 = wrap(self.trainer.model.transformers1)
        self.trainer.model.transformer_0 = wrap(self.trainer.model.transformer_0)
        self.trainer.model.transformer_1 = wrap(self.trainer.model.transformer_1)
        self.trainer.model.transformers_out = wrap(self.trainer.model.transformers_out)


    def forward(self, parts):
        x, indexes_a, batch_index = parts
        x = torch.squeeze(self.pos_embed(x.transpose(1,2)).transpose(1,2))
        x = x[batch_index]
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.transformers1(x)
        x = x.to(torch.float32)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.to_patches(x)
        N, P, C, X, Y = x.shape
        x = x.view(N*P, C, X, Y)
        # x = torch.index_select(x, 0, indexes_a)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        #this is where I print the amount of memory taken up
        print(get_gpu_memory()) 
        x = self.transformer_0(x)
        print(get_gpu_memory()) 
        #transformer_1 is where I get a cuda out of memory error
        x = self.transformer_1(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.original_model.from_patched(x).unsqueeze(0)
        x = self.transformers_out(x)
        x = x.to(torch.float32)
        x = self.conv_out(x)
        x = self.out_layer(x)
        return self.to_patches(x).flatten(0,1).contiguous()

    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        lr_list = [1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-2]
        initial_lr = lr_list[0]
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.trainer.model.parameters(), lr=initial_lr, momentum=0.3)
        scheduler = CustomLRScheduler(optimizer, lr_list)
        return [optimizer], [scheduler]

    def cross_entropy_loss(self, logits, labels):
        loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(logits.float(), labels)
        return loss

    def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
        input_batch, output_batch = train_batch
        output_batch = output_batch.squeeze()
        input_batch[1] = input_batch[1].squeeze()
        if(len(output_batch.shape) == 2):
            output_batch = torch.unsqueeze(output_batch, 0)
        total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in self.parameters())
        logits = self.forward(input_batch)
        gpu_memory = get_gpu_memory()
        for idx, (used, total) in enumerate(gpu_memory):
            print('gpu',idx,'used',used,'of memory')
            print('gpu',idx,'used',total,'total memory')
            self.log(f'gpu_{idx}_memory_used', used, on_step=True, on_epoch=False)
            self.log(f'gpu_{idx}_memory_total', total, on_step=True, on_epoch=False)
        print(gpu_memory)

        print(logits.shape, output_batch.shape)
        correct=logits.argmax(dim=1).eq(output_batch).sum().item()
        total=self.batch_size
        loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, output_batch)
        self.log("train_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True, sync_dist=True)
        self.store_losses_printing.append(loss) 
        logs={"train_loss": loss}
        self.store_correct_number.append(correct)
        self.store_correct_percent.append(correct / (output_batch.shape[0] * output_batch.shape[1] * output_batch.shape[2]))
        batch_dictionary={
            #REQUIRED: It ie required for us to return "loss"
            "loss": loss,
             
            #optional for batch logging purposes
            "log": logs,
 
            # info to be used at epoch end 
            "correct": correct,
            "total": total
        }
        return batch_dictionary
    
    def on_train_epoch_end(self):
        loss = sum(output.item() for output in self.store_losses_printing) / len(self.store_losses_printing)
        correct = sum(output for output in self.store_correct_number) / len(self.store_correct_number)
        correct_percent = sum(output for output in self.store_correct_percent) / len(self.store_correct_percent)
        self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("average_correct", correct, global_step=self.current_epoch)
        self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("average_correct_percent", correct_percent, global_step=self.current_epoch)
        print('')
        print('For epoch {}: Average returned loss: {}, Average correct: {}, Correct Percentage Average: {}'.format(self.current_epoch, loss, correct, correct_percent))
        self.store_losses_printing.clear()
        self.store_correct_percent.clear()
        self.store_correct_number.clear()

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        # print(self.trainer.model)
        if next(self.conv1.parameters()).device != self.device:
            self.conv1.to(self.device)
            self.conv2.to(self.device)
            self.bn1.to(self.device)
            self.bn2.to(self.device)
            self.conv_out.to(self.device)

        inputs, output_batch, name = batch
        print(inputs[0].dtype)
        
        output_batch = output_batch.cpu()
        output_batch[torch.where(output_batch == 2)] = 1
        inputs[1] = inputs[1].squeeze()
        output_batch = output_batch.squeeze()
        if(len(output_batch.shape) == 2):
            output_batch = torch.unsqueeze(output_batch, 0)
        
        logits = self.forward(inputs).cpu()
        correct=logits.argmax(dim=1).eq(output_batch).sum().item()
        total=self.batch_size

        loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, output_batch)

        self.log("val_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True, sync_dist=True)
        self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("val_current_loss", loss.item(), global_step=0)
        self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("val_current_correct", correct, global_step=0)
        gpu_memory = get_gpu_memory()
        for idx, (used, total) in enumerate(gpu_memory):
            print('gpu',idx,'used',used,'of memory')
            print('gpu',idx,'used',total,'total memory')
        print(gpu_memory)

        return {'val_loss':loss, 'total':total, 'correct':correct}


This is my get_gpu_memory() code:
import subprocess

def get_gpu_memory():
    """Get the current GPU memory usage."""
    try:
        result = subprocess.check_output(
            ['nvidia-smi', '--query-gpu=memory.used,memory.total', '--format=csv,nounits,noheader'],
            encoding='utf-8'
        )
        # The result is a string, split it into a list of strings
        gpu_memory = [line.split(', ') for line in result.strip().split('\n')]
        return [(int(used), int(total)) for used, total in gpu_memory]
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Error fetching GPU memory usage:", e)
        return []

This is how I set up the trainer and model using pytorch_lightning:

bregmas = torch.load("dataset/training/bregmas_blurred_n.pt")
output_batch = torch.load("dataset/training/right_masks_blurred.pt")
input_batch = torch.load("dataset/training/right_inputs_blurred.pt")

names_val = torch.load("dataset/validation/names.pt")
bregmas_val = torch.load("dataset/validation/bregmas.pt")
output_val = torch.load("dataset/validation/right_masks.pt")
input_val = torch.load("dataset/validation/right_inputs.pt")


r_model = LightningModel_distributed_patch_16()


dataset = MyDataset_model_num(input_batch, output_batch, idx_num, indexes=bregmas, batch_size=1024)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, num_workers=4, shuffle=True)
logger = pl.loggers.TensorBoardLogger('tb_logs', name='segmentation_log_right_blurred_v2_'+version+'_'+str(idx_num), version="right_idx_"+str(idx_num))
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
        dirpath=directory,  # Directory to save the checkpoints
        filename='{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}',  # Filename template
        save_top_k=-1,  # Save all checkpoints
        save_weights_only=False,  # Save the full model
        every_n_epochs=1  # Save every epoch
    )
mixed_precision_policy = MixedPrecision(
    param_dtype=torch.float16,
    reduce_dtype=torch.float16,
    buffer_dtype=torch.float16
)

fsdp_strategy = FSDPStrategy(accelerator='cuda', 
                             cpu_offload=True, 
                             auto_wrap_policy=None, 
                             mixed_precision=mixed_precision_policy) #offloads model to cpu when able, there is no made wrap policy (manually done in model), and train model using 16 bit floats
Trainer = pl.Trainer(precision=32,
                     default_root_dir="segmentation_models/", 
                     strategy = fsdp_strategy,
                     devices=[0,1], 
                     logger=logger, 
                     callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])

val_dataset = MyDataset_model_num_validation(input_val, output_val, idx_num, bregmas_val, names_val, batch_size=1024)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=1, num_workers=1)
Trainer.fit(r_model, train_dataloader, val_dataloader)

So when I look at the output on how much memory is used, before the x = self.transformer_0(x) it outputs [(16575, 81559), (3, 81559)], meaning 16575MB of memory used on GPU 0 and 3 MB of memory being used on GPU 1 and there is a total capacitance of 81559 MB, and then after x = self.transformer_0(x) the output was [(50421, 81559), (3, 81559)], but then there is a memory CUDA Allocation error once the x = self.transformer_1(x) is called within that module. I am so confused, I thought that FSDP was supposed to automatically shard my model across multiple GPUs? is it possible to manually have different parts of my model processed on different GPUs? I would really appreciate the help, if my question can be formatted or made more clear in any way please comment.

You need to define wrap policy, otherwise it will wrap everything into 1 module.
Wrap policy is per nn.Module unit. I have not myself written my own network, so I give can only give you an example with fine-tuning that I did. For Donut model, the wrap policy would look like this:
from transformers.models.donut.modeling_donut_swin import DonutSwinEncoder, DonutSwinStage
from transformers.models.mbart import MBartForCausalLM    
wrap_policy = {DonutSwinEncoder, MBartForCausalLM, DonutSwinModel}
fsdp_strategy = FSDPStrategy(accelerator='cuda', 
                             cpu_offload=True, 
                             auto_wrap_policy=wrap_policy, 
                             mixed_precision=mixed_precision_policy)

